# NameError: global name Error in Class , but is actually defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I have the following code, where somehow the class is not honoring the self. name., when I access the class variable in a function, it is complaining that the self.variable is not a global variable. Any ideas why?

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer , String, Float, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base=declarative_base() 

class Designs(Base):
  __tablename__='designs'
  design_name=Column(String(80),nullable=False,primary_key=True)

  @property
  def serialize(self):
      return{
        'design_name': self.design_name,
       }
```

When I access the class, design_name is there, but somehow python is complaining it is not declared as global? Any Ideas?

let's say temp declared with the Designs class, and is filled with value for design_name

```
  print temp.design_name
  print temp.serialize()

xpc_fp   <----- print i.design_name works
```

serialize command does not work** and gives the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "database_setup.py", line 149, in serialize
    'design_name': self.design_name,
NameError: global name 'design_name' is not defined
```

Comment: Sure, I'll have a guess. The code you are running is not the code you posted. In your actual code, you don't have the quotes around `design_name` in the dictionary.

Comment: Your code cannot produce this error. Make sure you save the file, then rerun.

Comment: call it like this `i.serialize` without the parenthese

Comment: Seems to me as if design_name is a static variable, and not accessed with the `self.` operator (as it hasn't been instantiated using `__init__(self): self.design_name = ...` - I believe you can just remove the `self.` from `self.design_name`. Very well could be wrong though.

Comment: @Aeroblop No, it is a *class level attribute*, which can be accessed from an instance using either `self.class_variable` but rather, you should use `MyClass.class_variable`. If you *assign* to `self.class_variable`, it actually **shadows** `MyClass.class_variable` in your instance.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, thank you! Learn something new everyday :p

Comment: @shx2 Looks like that was the problem. I was loading the data from an SQL database, and it is corrupted... thats why it wasn't callable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define serialize as a property - so you should treat it as a property.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer , String, Float, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base=declarative_base()

class Designs(Base):
  __tablename__='designs'
  design_name=Column(String(80),nullable=False,primary_key=True)

  @property
  def serialize(self):
    return{
      'design_name': self.design_name,
    }



temp = Designs(design_name='HELLO THERE')
print(temp.design_name)
print(temp.serialize)
```

so drop the parenthesis from the .serialize call

output:
HELLO THERE
{'design_name': 'HELLO THERE'}